memory consumption of virtual threads in Java
I am looking for a way to determine the exact difference in runtime memory consumption of virtual threads and platform threads in Java.
I have tried to use "jbellis/jamm: Java Agent for Memory Measurements" but it does not support virtual Threads.
MXBean sometimes returned negative memory consumption.
Also tried to use the "jmap -histo" command and JMC with a .jfr-file but I do not really know what to look for.

Why do you expect to see a difference in memory usage?  Threads, whether platform or virtual, use little memory in and of themselves.  That's not the resource that is potentially conserved by using virtual threads instead of platform threads.

@JohnBollinger stacks are pretty damn large once you start talking about ten thousand threads. (Let's say a 256k stack, that's 2.5GB!! - easily managed by giving the threads that you have a ton of much less stack and ensuring the code they need to run can deal with that, but, you do have to write that, you don't get it for free) - The key sentence in your comment is certainly relevant here though: Virtual threads don't help to reduce this.

In Project Loom talks by Ron Pressler, I recall him saying OS threads typically get 1 or 2 megs to start. More importantly, the thread stack grows but does not shrink, in dramatic contrast to Java Virtual Threads. Though not authoritative, this page by Ariadne Conill in 2021 shows modern OSes assigning default thread stack sizes of half-meg (ex: Apple OSes), one meg (ex: MS Windows), two megs (ex: FreeBSD), or eight megs in the case of GNU/Linux.

By the way, anyone interested in this topic might enjoy this talk by Ron Pressler, of the Project Loom team at Oracle: Continuations - Under the Covers #JVMLS with nitty-gritty technical details.
